# Calling an API in parallel using Node

Tags: node.js

I want to stress test my API and call it multiple times in parallel to get an idea of performance.

I am almost there with the code, and as someone new to JS, I am hoping to fix my code as follows:

1. Call each request in Parallel
2. Log out when each individual request is finished
3. Log out the time taken for each individual request

At the minute, the function waits until all calls have finished before it logs out the data.  I assume this is because I am using `Promise.all()`?

```
import fetch from 'node-fetch';

var requestAsync = function(url) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        var req = request(url, (err, response, body) => {
            if (err) return reject(err, response, body);
            resolve(JSON.parse(body));
        });
    });
};

const urls = ["url1", "url2", "url3", "url4"];

var getParallelData = async function() {
    //transform requests into Promises, await all
    var startTime = performance.now()
    try {
        var data = await Promise.all(urls.map(requestAsync));
    } catch (err) {
        console.error("ERROR: " + err);
    }
    var endTime = performance.now()
    console.log(data);
    console.log(`Call  took ${(endTime - startTime) / 1000} seconds`)
}

getParallelData();
```

Edit:  I have been continually trying to evolve this to suit my needs and this is what I have now.  I think its doing what I expect but as long as its not waiting for the first request to finish before starting the next.

```
import request from 'request'

var requestAsync = function(url) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      var req = request.get({
        url : url,
        time : true
      },function(err, response){
        console.log('Request time in seconds', (response.elapsedTime / 1000));
      });
    });
};

const urls = ["url1", "url2", "url3", "url4"];


var getParallelData = async function() {

  for(const url of dev_urls) {
    requestAsync(url)
 }
}
getParallelData();
```

Comment: Instead of writing a script yourself for stress testing your API, you can use Artillery which works out-of-the-box. It is designed to use with Node API's and does everything you want. See: https://www.artillery.io/docs

Comment: Thanks I'll look into that.  When I say stress testing, thats a bit of a stretch.  I just want to see how the app API performs under concurrent api calls.  Artillery may do the job tho

Comment: You should implement multithreading or use a better tool like jmeter.